# Why tomcat is not required in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new in spring boot. can anyone help me out with this? Why tomcat is not required in spring boot? Any help well be great.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-embedded-web-servers

Comment: can you just explain in short why be don't need it?

Comment: You haven't even clicked the link, have you? "*Each Spring Boot web application includes an embedded web server. This feature leads to a number of how-to questions, including how to change the embedded server and how to configure the embedded server. This section answers those questions.*" This literally is the first paragraph of the doc I linked.

Comment: Because you can use jetty instead? What are you asking?

Comment: Why would it be required in spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

A Spring Boot Application contains the binaries for the server (example, tomcat.jar). It means you can run a web application as a normal Java application.

As you can see in the following text from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-embedded-web-servers, you can change the server to a server of your choice:

> For servlet stack applications, the spring-boot-starter-web includes
>   Tomcat by including spring-boot-starter-tomcat, but you can use
>   spring-boot-starter-jetty or spring-boot-starter-undertow instead.

Comment: "*A Spring Boot Application contains the binaries for the server*" - The wording can be misleading. The doc is quite verbose about this: ["*If your classpath contains the necessary bits to start a web server, Spring Boot will automatically start it.*"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-disable-web-server). Thus, it is enough if the web server is on the classpath.